# $\int_{u_n}^1 \dfrac{e^t}t=n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

- $\int_{u_n}^1 \dfrac{e^t}t  \, dt=n$
- $v_n= n + \ln u_n$
- What is the limit of $v_n$ ?
- Equivalent of $v_n$
- What is the nature of $\sum u_n$ ?

---

My attempt :

- Let $\phi(t)= \dfrac{e^t}t$
- $\phi$ is increasing on  $[1, +\infty]$, so $u_n$ is defined
- $n + \ln u_n = \int_{u_n}^{1} \dfrac{e^t-1}t \, dt$
- $n + \ln u_n \to \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{e^t-1}t \, dt  = K< \infty$
- $n + \ln u_n = e^{K+ o(1)}$
- $u_n \sim e^{-n} e^K$
- $ \sum u_n < \infty$

$
\begin{align*}
v_n-K&=\int_0^{u_n} \frac{1-e^t}{t} dt \\
&= \int_0^{u_n} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n-1}}{n!} dt \\
&= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{u_n} \frac{t^{n-1}}{n!} dt \\
&= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{t^n}{nn!} \right]_0^{u_n} \\
&= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u_n^n}{nn!}\\
\end{align*}$

I have more or less the answer.
Could you help improve it or suggest a different method ?

Comment: Did you mean to write $v_n=n+\ln u_n$ in the second bullet point?

Comment: Thanks, I have changed.